# Do high powered wifi adapters exist for point to point wifi networks?

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11

I've been looking for a more powerful card but non seem to exist. It's necessary for me to use a high powered adapter as I have a point to point network setup between 2 buildings using TP-Link bi-directional antennas.

Currently I use an Alfa AWUS036NHA. I can boost the power in my OS to 30dBm but the longevity of the device suffers. I have to replace the adapter at least once every 9 months.

Comment: Removed off-topic request for product recommendations

Comment: The device power and antenna gain are regulated by the government. There are limits on the power, and most Wi-Fi devices can do the full allowed power. Unfortunately, questions about consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: 36dbm is allowed for point to point in my country.

Comment: @RonTrunk The response I wanted to know was whether or not high powered devices exist. I wasn't referring to specific brands. In businesses that use point to point wifi networks there must exist devices with more power/range than standard wifi cards. What are these devices? Maybe I could have worded the question better. Nevermind.

Answer (score 2):

The radiated power of WiFi transmitters is limited by regulation, so there are legal limits to how much you can transmit.  The maximum radiated power is dependent on both the radio and the antenna, so if you increase your antenna gain, you might have to decrease your transmitter power to stay within limits.

Here are the limits for the US:

```
Channel          EIRP (mW) dBm
1-11               1000    30
36, 40, 44, 48      200    23
52, 56, 60, 64     1000    30
149, 153, 157, 161 4000    36
```

And here is a [list for other countries](https://w.wol.ph/2015/08/28/maximum-wifi-transmission-power-country/).

Comment: I am aware of the law. Why would you assume I'm not? In the UK the legal limit license free is 1W ... which is 30dbm. Your link is incorrect for the UK. We use band b at 1W without any legal issues. If we wanted to use band c ... that's a different story. But that's not the question asked :)

Comment: I am aware of the law. Why would you assume I'm not? In the UK the legal limit license free is 1W ... which is 30dbm. Yet, you felt it necessary to inform me of information I already knew after voting to close the question off topic.  Your list is incorrect. We use band b at 1W without any legal issues. If we wanted to use band c ... that's a different story.